# The need of modulation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas, radio-frequency

Why is the transmitted signal modulated rather than sending the whole signal as a radio wave?

Why is it necessary to modulate the wave? I do understand there are quite advantages of modulation but isn't it better to just send the signal as a radio wave?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation#Noise_reduction

Comment: Could this reasoning be correct? Not all signals can be transmitted as radio signal because maybe the information signal might not have enough frequency to be transmitted as a RADIO signal?

Comment: Next time you can google it yourself https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-advantage-of-frequency-modulation

Comment: No no you got me wrong, I am aware of the advantages of FM such as short aerial, less error. What I am asking is it even possible for some signals to be transmitted directly as a radio wave. For a radiowave the minimum frequency is 3kHz. What if my signal had a frequency of 100Hz? Can it be directly transmitted as a radiowave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say,

> Not all signals can be transmitted as radio signal because maybe the information signal might not have enough frequency to be transmitted as a radio signal.

Radio propagates much better at higher frequencies than the range of human hearing, and it's easier to build antennas and so on for those wavelengths.

In addition, the use of modulation to park the radio transmission at some higher frequency enables things like the simultaneous use of multiple stations, each with its own channel, which is quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

A modulated radio carrier *is* a "radio wave".

A unmodulated carrier would be a pure sine.  That carries no dynamic information.  All the dynamic information content is in the *changing* of a carrier.  We call this changing "modulation".

You can also look at this in the frequency space.  A pure sine has a bandwidth of 0, so doesn't carry information.